# JavaScript function won't fire on button click

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I've just started teaching myself JavaScript and am doing some basic exercises. Right now I'm trying to make a function that takes in three values and prints out the largest. However, the function refuses to fire upon button click. I tried making a separate, very simple function just for debugging and it refuses to fire as well. I've written other practice functions in almost the exact same manner (they had two parameters as opposed to three) that work fine. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type = "text/javascript">
<!--

//Define a function Max() that takes three numbers as 
//arguments and returns the largest of them.
function Boo(){
    document.write("boo");
    alert("boo");
}


function Max(p1, p2, p3){
    document.write(p1+p2+p3);
    alert('BOO!')

    document.write(document.getElementById('value1').value);

    var max = Number(p1);
    v2 = Number(p2):
    v3 = Number(p3);    

    if (v2 > max)
        max = v2;
    if (v3 > max)
        max = v3;

    document.write(max);
}
-->
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
<form>
    <input type="text" id="value1" name="value1"/><br />
    <input type="text" id="value2" name="value2"/><br />
    <input type="text" id="value3" name="value3"/><br />
    <input type = "button" 
    onclick="Boo()" 
    value = "Compare!"/>
    <!-- onclick="Max(document.getElementById('value1').value,
                 document.getElementById('value2').value,
                 document.getElementById('value3').value)" -->
</form>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Does Boo() work? If not then check if JS is enabled in your browser

Comment: Well in your max function you're missing semi-colon at the end of the second line which would cause it to fail.

Comment: You should use `var` for all your variables, like `v2` and `v3`, to avoid implicitly using globals in javascript (multiple instances of Max or other functions with the name `v2` will overwrite each other's values).

Comment: For future reference, `Math.max(1,2,3)` -> `3`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  v2 = Number(p2):
```

should be

```
v2 = Number(p2);
```

Also, look into the developer tools for whatever browser you are using to find simple syntax errors like this. (In most browsers you can press F12).

Comment: *headdesk, that would be it. Thanks. I tried getting Firebug for stupid things like this but long story short, I cannot :(. Are there any programs similar you would recommend?

Comment: The latest version of firefox has some nice developer tools. That would work just as well. Or try pressing Shift+CTRL+J (in firefox)

Answer (score 2):

chrome developer tool says it has syntax error!

```
v2 = Number(p2):
```

should be:

```
v2 = Number(p2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your javascript functions are commented out with `<!-- -->`

Comment: Actually, that's valid. It's for all those browsers that don't support javascript. It's VERY old school. :). See: http://javascript.about.com/library/blhtmcmt.htm

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByName('to_compare');
    var elementsAsArray = [].slice.call(elements);
    var numberValues = elementsAsArray.map(function(x) {
        return Number(x.value)
    });
    return Math.max.apply(this, numberValues);
```

Full demo, including using `console.log` rather than `document.write`, also including how to append to document without clearing it: http://jsfiddle.net/yYhjD/1/

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

function compare() {
    var elements = [].slice.call(document.getElementsByName('to_compare'));
    var numberValues = elements.map(function(x){return Number(x.value)});
    return Math.max.apply(this, numberValues);
}

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="value1" name="to_compare" value="-10"/>
    <input type="text" id="value2" name="to_compare" value="080"/>
    <input type="text" id="value3" name="to_compare" value="79"/>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" onclick="console.log(compare())" value="Compare!"/>
</body>
```